# Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_3 to have shape (1375, 1) but got array with shape (5511, 101)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)        (None, 5511, 101)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_13 (Conv1D)           (None, 1375, 196)         297136    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_27 (Batc (None, 1375, 196)         784       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)   (None, 1375, 196)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_34 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 196)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru_18 (GRU)                 (None, 1375, 128)         124800    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_35 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_28 (Batc (None, 1375, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
gru_19 (GRU)                 (None, 1375, 128)         98688     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_36 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_29 (Batc (None, 1375, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_37 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_11 (TimeDis (None, 1375, 1)           129       
=================================================================

Total params: 522,561
Trainable params: 521,657
Non-trainable params: 904

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_3 to have shape (1375, 1) but got array with shape (5511, 101)
```

i'm giving .npy file as input to the cnn layer. array is of size (5, 5511, 101)
is it problem with the input array ?
how to overcome that value error . i'm using keras (jupyter notebook).I am unable to find any solution .any help would be appreciated.

code snippet @ErselEr...this is the code i'm using to build the model

```
def model(input_shape):

    X_input = Input(shape = input_shape)
    y = Input(shape = input_shape)
    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Step 1: CONV layer (≈4 lines)
    X = Conv1D(196, kernel_size=15, strides=4)(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                 # Batch normalization
    X = Activation('relu')(X)   # ReLu activation
    X = 
    X = Dropout(0.8)(X) # dropout (use 0.8)

    # Step 2: First GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
    X = GRU(units = 128, return_sequences = True)(X) # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
    X = Dropout(0.8)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)  # Batch normalization



    # Step 3: Second GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
    X = GRU(units = 128, return_sequences = True)(X)   # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
    X = Dropout(0.8)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                  # Batch normalization
       # dropout (use 0.8)



    # Step 4: Time-distributed dense layer (≈1 line)
    X = TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid"))(X) # time distributed  (sigmoid)


    ### END CODE HERE ###

    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X)

    return model
```

Comment: Could you please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then review your question? Also, you should give more information about your question. In which case you are getting this error message, which framework/tool you are using, what you are trying to do... I guess you are using Keras but you did not mentioned anything about that. Please provide more information to users. By the way, if you flatten (5511,101) shaped data it will create (5511 * 101, 1) = (556611, 1) which is not you are seeking for. Check your steps.

Comment: i'm using keras , working in jupyter notebook.The model is to detect triggerword....my question is  - the input of TimeDistributed dense layer is of shape(1375,1) but my model is taking (5511,101) as input. how to convert that input shape of (5511,101) to (1375,1).

Comment: @ErselEr  can u help me with this please

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet that you created this Neural Network?

Comment: @ErselEr ...i have attached the code snippet in my main question .check once

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work properly. I made-up an example with randomly created data. Do not take care of accuracy and losses since I created this example to show that the model can be compiled and trained without getting errors.

Import required packages:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Activation, BatchNormalization, TimeDistributed, Dense, Dropout, GRU
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
```

Then use model function(I deleted only one line of code in Step 1):

```
def model(input_shape):

    X_input = Input(shape = input_shape)
    y = Input(shape = input_shape)
    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Step 1: CONV layer (≈4 lines)
    X = Conv1D(196, kernel_size=15, strides=4)(X_input)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                 # Batch normalization
    X = Activation('relu')(X)   # ReLu activation
    X = Dropout(0.8)(X) # dropout (use 0.8)

    # Step 2: First GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
    X = GRU(units = 128, return_sequences = True)(X) # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
    X = Dropout(0.8)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)  # Batch normalization



    # Step 3: Second GRU Layer (≈4 lines)
    X = GRU(units = 128, return_sequences = True)(X)   # GRU (use 128 units and return the sequences)
    X = Dropout(0.8)(X)                                 # dropout (use 0.8)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)                                  # Batch normalization
       # dropout (use 0.8)



    # Step 4: Time-distributed dense layer (≈1 line)
    X = TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid"))(X) # time distributed  (sigmoid)


    ### END CODE HERE ###

    model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X)

    return model
```

Create the model:

```
input_shape = (5511, 101)
m = model(input_shape)
m.summary()
```

**Output:**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_27 (InputLayer)        (None, 5511, 101)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_12 (Conv1D)           (None, 1375, 196)         297136    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (Batc (None, 1375, 196)         784       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 1375, 196)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_13 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 196)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
gru_9 (GRU)                  (None, 1375, 128)         124800    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_14 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 1375, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
gru_10 (GRU)                 (None, 1375, 128)         98688     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 1375, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (Batc (None, 1375, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_5 (TimeDist (None, 1375, 1)           129       
=================================================================
Total params: 522,561
Trainable params: 521,657
Non-trainable params: 904
```

Compile model with required parameters:

```
# initiate Adam optimizer
opt = Adam(lr=0.0001)

# Let's train the model using Adam
m.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Create training(made-up) data with 100 instances to test the model:

```
x_train = np.random.rand(100, 5511, 101)
y_train = np.random.rand(100, 1375, 1)
```

And finally fit data to model for training:

```
results = m.fit(
 x_train, y_train,
 epochs= 2,
 batch_size = 10,
 validation_data = (x_train, y_train)
)
```

**Output:**

```
Train on 100 samples, validate on 100 samples
Epoch 1/2
100/100 [==============================] - 16s 157ms/step - loss: 0.9138 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.7009 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
100/100 [==============================] - 13s 130ms/step - loss: 0.9135 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.7006 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

As I said before, I **made-up** this example without any information about your goal for training, therefore don't care about losses etc. I have just used `binary_crossentropy` blindly because my purpose is just to show that the model is working.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: By the way while fitting the data to model using `validation_data = (x_train, y_train)` is not a proper way. You should create a real validation data :)